# python flask: share data using the global app object

Tags: python, flask

I am looking for a ways to share global data across all views of the flask application

`__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.gcp = googleCloudSessionObjectA()
```

`aview.py`

```
from flask import current_app as app

@app.route('/abc')
def foo():
    print(app.gcp)  # here it prints the string representation of A
    app.gcp = googleCloudSessionObjectB() # this one does not change the global app object
    return render_template('base.html')
```

I want to be able to change the value of `app.gcp` in a view after importing the `current_app` object. And I want this value to be available throughout the application.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use session variables using os?

Comment: Because in reality I dont want to store a string ("dog"), I want to store a python object for global use (to be exact its a session object for google cloud pltform).

Comment: If I want to make only string values available throughout the flask application I could use a datastore such as memcached. But I need to do it with a python object

Comment: Have you checked https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/ ?

Comment: I am aware of flasks configuration. But whats the connection to my issue at hand?

Comment: It would be great if you could add that in the question. As there is a difference between storing primitive data types and complex python structures.

Answer (score -3):

## please try  use global app.bar as following example ->

```
x = 15
def change(): 

    # using a global keyword 
    global x 

    # increment value of a by 5 
    x = x + 5
    print("Value of x inside a function :", x) 
change() 
print("Value of x outside a function :", x)
```

Comment: and how this will works in `production`? I mean using `gunicorn` or `uwsgi` with multiple `workers`?

Comment: On addition to that, global variables should be ignored as much as possible. They can sometimes be really painful and dangerous if you don't exactly know what you are doing with it.